# How to fix Maven project-info-reports:dependency-management exception

Tags: spring, maven

After improving my POM a bit (with findbugs, pmd, checkstyle) I got an exception when running:

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependency-management

[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0 from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0 in http://192.168.50.3:8080/nexus/content/groups/bendit-snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of bendit-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced for project javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.RepositoryUtils.getMavenProjectFromRepository(RepositoryUtils.java:298)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.getDependencyRow(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:260)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForScope(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForAllScopes(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderSectionProjectDependencies(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderBody(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:136)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReportRenderer.render(AbstractMavenReportRenderer.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.DependencyManagementReport.executeReport(DependencyManagementReport.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.AbstractProjectInfoReport.execute(AbstractProjectInfoReport.java:234)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0 in http://192.168.50.3:8080/nexus/content/groups/bendit-snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of bendit-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:344)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0 in http://192.168.50.3:8080/nexus/content/groups/bendit-snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of bendit-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 38 more
```

Because that is no dependency from my project, I tried to find ou whats the problem - updating to the latest Maven 3.3.9 and Java 1.8.0_121 doesn't help.

`maven-project-info-reports-plugin` version 2.9 is also the latest available one at this time.

So I asked [mvnrepository.com](https://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/com.springsource.javax.inject/1.0.0) for the artifact, which says that it is hosted on artifacts.alfresco.com. But there [the repository has no `pom` or `jar`!](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/javax/inject/com.springsource.javax.inject/)

Last but not least I now downloaded the artifact from [ebr.springsource.com](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail;jsessionid=2944DD73A76F65EF77D23DAD2D8CC739.jvm1?name=com.springsource.javax.inject&version=1.0.0).
I guess that there must be something wrong with repository dependencies in a Maven plugin (dependency). Because I was not able to find out more, I hope some else can help in fixing this?

Comment: Is this possibly a transitive dependency of your project's dependencies? If not, it is primarily not the plugin's fault if a transitive dependency of [dependencies declared for a plugin](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/2.9/maven-project-info-reports-plugin-2.9.pom) isn't available any longer at the place it obviously once was.

Comment: You have configuration issues in your repository manager: `Failure to find javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0 in http://192.168.50.3:8080/nexus/content/groups/bendit-snapshots` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can (also) be but the mentioned artifact isn't availble at all in the repo the OP mentioned and which I linked in the question.

Comment: I have my doubts that the given artifact:  `javax.inject:com.springsource.javax.inject:pom:1.0.0` cause I assume the artifactId is wrong. Nor can it be found in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22javax.inject%22%20AND%20a%3A%22com.springsource.javax.inject%22%20AND%20v%3A%221.0.0%22). I assume the artiact which is meant: is `javax.inject:javax.inject:1` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise It can be downloaded from the [SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail;jsessionid=2944DD73A76F65EF77D23DAD2D8CC739.jvm1?name=com.springsource.javax.inject&version=1.0.0).

Comment: Yes I know but the setup in the repository manager is wrong..or simply missing the SpringSource repository.